# How to create a symbolic link that points to the latest directory in a target directory?

Tags: linux, bash

I've been reading various Stack Overflow similar questions and I still am having trouble creating a symbolic link that gets successfully created pointing to the latest directory in a given target-directory.

Back story of this is that we have a deployment script that needs to use the latest release version within a directory that is referenced with a symbolic link.

For experimenting with this structure, I've created a simple directory "testSymLinks/target/" and have the following sub-directories of target as "test1/", "test2/", etc. So overall I have this as my structure:

```
testSymLinks/
--target/
**latest (symbolic link)
-----test1/
-----test2/ (created second / as the latest, new directory)
```

First, I've been trying to create a symbolic link "latest" (sitting in "testSymLinks/") to point to the latest sub-directory of "target/", which is "test2/", with the following attempts:

ATTEMPT 1:

```
ln -sf target/`ls -rt target | tail -n1` latest
```

[image: Link since apparently I cannot post pictures yet and I need a backtick #NotNewbieFriendly]

ATTEMPT 2:

```
ln -sf target/`ls -td -- */ | head -n 1` latest
```

[image: Link since apparently I cannot post pictures yet and I need a backtick #NotNewbieFriendly]

Both of these attempts still have the symlink "latest" pointing to the directory "target/" instead of the latest sub-directory within "target/" so far. I've been checking by running a *ls -lrt* and a *readlink -f latest* to verify.

[image: Link since apparently I cannot post pictures yet #NotNewbieFriendly]

I'm trying to see what I'm missing here and was hoping to find any advice, explanations, and suggestions so that I may not only be able to solve my problem, but to also understand why it's not working in the first place.

Comment: Don't parse ls output. use `find`. The directory with the biggest number or with latest creation date is the "latest"?

Comment: The latest creation date. So if I added test0/ that would be the latest directory that I would need the symlink to point to.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me to create a symlink pointing to the last directory created in a folder:

```
$ mkdir target/f
$ mkdir target
$ mkdir target/a
$ mkdir target/b
$ mkdir target/g
$ mkdir target/c
$ mkdir target/h
$ mkdir target/d
$ ls target
a  b  c  d  f  g  h
$ ln -s $(ls -t --group-directories-first target | head -n 1) target/latest
$ ls target -la
total 0
drwxrwxrwx 1 paulos paulos 4096 Apr 12 18:18 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 paulos paulos 4096 Apr 12 18:17 ..
drwxrwxrwx 1 paulos paulos 4096 Apr 12 18:17 a
drwxrwxrwx 1 paulos paulos 4096 Apr 12 18:17 b
drwxrwxrwx 1 paulos paulos 4096 Apr 12 18:17 d
drwxrwxrwx 1 paulos paulos 4096 Apr 12 18:17 f
drwxrwxrwx 1 paulos paulos 4096 Apr 12 18:17 g
drwxrwxrwx 1 paulos paulos 4096 Apr 12 18:17 h
lrwxrwxrwx 1 paulos paulos    1 Apr 12 18:18 latest -> d
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$ ln -sf "$(ls -1dt target/*/ | sed 1q)" latest
```

note that there is no error handling...

Answer (score 0):

So the task is composed of two subtasks:

- Finding the latest directory
- Creating the symlink

The second step is easy, the first one is hard.

This is what I have end up with:

```
ln -sf "target/$(find target -type d -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -printf "%T@ %f\n" |
    sort -n -k1 | tail -n1 | cut -d' ' -f2-)" latest
```

`find` prints directories inside `target` directory with it's last modification time in unix timestamp `%T@` and prints the directory name `$f` separated with newlines. Then I numeric sort the list using the first field, get the last line and remove the timestamp. After that the creation of the symlink stays the same.

I have found that your first solution work, however I would advise to at least use `-1` option with `ls`. The second one creates the symlink to `target/target/test2`, you should loose the first `target/`. Note that `ls` is highly customized utility, mostly is aliased to some `ls --color -F` and is not advised to use in scripts. Also backticks ` ` are deprecated, use `$( .. )` instead.